# Give date as iso format

Tags: isodate, date

Currently, when I use `\date{}` for an old document, I put the explicit form of the date. But this is a problem because I print all my documents in two versions, a personal version (with the form   ) and a public one with the default settings.

So, I just want to give the date in a ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) and, depending of the global settings, all dates in the document have to follow one format.

So, I ask if there is a kind of `\displaydate` command witch take as argument the date in ISO format and display it according to the global setting.

So there is a package like that?

Comment: lookup `datetime2`. Documentation [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) or write `texdoc datetime2` in the terminal/commandline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) where you can define your date styles and interchange them within your document (or globally) via `\DTMsetdatestyle{<style>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{dashdate}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\number##1-\DTMenglishshortmonthname{##2}-\number##3}%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\begin{document}

\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}
\today% ...or \DTMtoday

\DTMsetdatestyle{dashdate}
\today% ...or \DTMtoday

\DTMdisplaydate{2015}{1}{1}{-1}% Ignore Day-Of-Week

\end{document}
```

`\DTMdisplaydate{<year>}{<month>}{<day>}{<dow>}` will display a hard-coded date in the current style.

Comment: \DTMtoday works for me, while \today still shows the original fomrat. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @MaxN: I see no difference between `\today` and `\DTMtoday` in my minimal example. Perhaps you are using a specialized `\documentclass` that adjusts/changes `\today`?

Comment: according to the manual ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf you should always specify the dow \DTMdisplaydate{2015}{1}{1}{-1}

Comment: @MaxN: It also mentions that `\today` might be affect if you load language-specific package like `babel` or `polyglossia`. In those instances, load order is important, and you have to load `datetime2` after them.