# How do I force maketitle to use ISO 8601 format for the date?

Tags: titles, date

I'm using Overleaf and `\maketitle` gives me

> Title
>   Author
>   9th May

How do I force LaTeX/Overleaf to give me

> Title
>   Author
>   2017-05-09

instead?

Comment: Use `\date{\the\year-\the\month-\the\day}` in your preamble (or whereever you set this kind of information).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315965/117534?

Comment: \date{2017-05-09}

Comment: `\the\year-\the\month-\the\day` doesn't work because it can give things like 2022-2-1.  See the answer below for a fix to that.  Also, what kind of dash does ISO8601 specify?  Maybe it should be `\the\year--\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month--\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it manually by using:

[image: date]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to forget the real manual way of specifying a date (which is not today).

```
\date{2017-05-14}
```

Will give *2017-5-14*.

```
\date{2017}
```

would give *2017*. `\date`  really is just a storage device with no knowledge of a date.

Comment: 2017-5-14 is not in ISO8601 format.